# Access json string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, json, servlets, arraylist

I have a `String` called json which has `ArrayList` values. I used Gson to convert the arraylist to json. I am passing the json to a javascript from servlet as a response in `POST`.

I get the response in js as `["1.343","73.6544","32.6454","34.453","43.565","23.454"]`. How to access these values in js with a variable individually(these are location coordinates). I want to use these values to display the location in my map.

How do i access these values in js. The value obtained in js is a string which contains arraylist. I used gson to convert to string.

This is js:

```
<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            data.toString();
            alert(data);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'GetLocationFromDB', true);
    xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

The `data` is value from servlet.
SErvlet:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(arraylist);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the response to Json and you will have access to the elements

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Read more on JSON.parse here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

As a simple test to should how JSON.parse works.

```
var x = JSON.parse('["1.343","73.6544","32.6454","34.453","43.565","23.454"]');
alert(x[0]) // alerts with 1.343
```

Here is what you should have.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json); 
        //or if you like alerts
        alert(json);
    }
}
xhr.open('POST', 'GetLocationFromDB', true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I tried to see the parsed var in `alert()` but there's no alert appearing. i did this `alert(JSON.parse(data))`. I even tried to convert `data` to string and parse. didnt work

Comment: then your data is empty.

Comment: it's not empty. before parsing, i could display it in the alert. it showed as `["1.343","73.6544","32.6454","34.453","43.565","23.454"]`  in the alert box.

Comment: `try { JSON.parse(data); } catch(error) { alert(error); }`

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: what is the output for this. `alert("@" + data + "@")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105994/discussion-between-dom-farr-and-brocolli).

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse your `data`.

`JSON.parse()` for parsing a string of JSON text into a javascript Object and `JSON.stringify` for turing a Javascript object into JSON text.

Comment: I tried to display the parsed var in `alert()` but there's no alert appearing.

Comment: use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`